# How to get values from a form in frontend and pass it to JAVA and display back in frontend using Angular

Tags: java, angular, xml, soap, frontend

This is a payment verification SOAP XML API that I managed to get it working in JAVA. The JAVA code will post XML request to a payment API using XML with SOAPAction headers and Body.  Then it will get a response from the API.

However I wish to create a simple Form in the Frontend using Angular (If this is the right approach) get the values from user input like `CardNum, CardType, CardCVC` and sending the values back to JAVA and the JAVA will then get the XML Response and display back to the Frontend webpage like `Transaction ID, Order Status, Order Reason, Transaction Status Payment`. I am still new in JAVA and Angular. Any pointers is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
public class Send_XML_Post_Request_1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
             String url = "https://onepay-services.uat.aws.emagin.eu/api/soap/payment";
             URL obj = new URL(url);
             HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
             con.setRequestMethod("POST");
             con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml");
             con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction","http://www.allianz-assistance.com/emagin/services/PaymentService/1.0/authorize");
             String CardType="VISA";
             String CardNum = "4444333322221111";
             String CardCVC = "425";
             String xml = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""
                        + "  xmlns:ns=\"http://www.allianz-assistance.com/emagin/services/PaymentService/1.0\">"
                    + "<soapenv:Header/>"
                    + "    <soapenv:Body>"
                    + "        <tns:authorize version=\"1.0\" xmlns:tns=\"http://www.allianz-assistance.com/emagin/services/PaymentService/1.0\" xmlns:emagin=\"http://www.mondial-assistance.com/ecommerce/schema/\">"
                    + "            <tns:globalRequestId>paymentOrder</tns:globalRequestId>"
                    + "            <tns:authentication>"
                    + "                <tns:userId>AWC_LIFEEUR</tns:userId>"
                    + "                <tns:password>awclifeeur$2018</tns:password>"
                    + "            </tns:authentication>"
                    + "            <tns:accountId>ACCOUNT_AWC_LIFEEUR</tns:accountId>"
                    + "            <tns:customerInformation>"
                    + "                <tns:partnerCode>ALS</tns:partnerCode>"
                    + "                <tns:buCode>CH</tns:buCode>"
                    + "            </tns:customerInformation>"
                    + "            <tns:paymentInformation>"
                    + "                <tns:paymentHolder>"
                    + "                    <tns:name>Charlie</tns:name>"
                    + "                    <tns:email>charlie@allianz.com</tns:email>"
                    + "                    <tns:address>"
                    + "                        <tns:address>11/22 Street1 Road1</tns:address>"
                    + "                        <tns:city>Penang</tns:city>"
                    + "                        <tns:country>ID</tns:country>"
                    + "                    </tns:address>"
                    + "                </tns:paymentHolder>"
                    + "                <tns:amount currency=\"USD\">33.33</tns:amount>"
                    + "                <tns:cardInformation>"
                    + "                    <tns:cardType>" + CardType + "</tns:cardType>"
                    + "                    <tns:cardNumber>" + CardNum +"</tns:cardNumber>"
                    + "                    <tns:cvc>" + CardCVC + "</tns:cvc>"
                    + "                    <tns:expiryDate month=\"10\" year=\"2023\"/>"
                    + "                </tns:cardInformation>"
                    + "                <tns:shopperInformation>"
                    + "                    <tns:browser>"
                    + "                        <tns:userAgentHeader>Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36</tns:userAgentHeader>"
                    + "                        <tns:acceptHeader>application/json, text/plain, */*</tns:acceptHeader>"
                    + "                    </tns:browser>"
                    + "                    <tns:ipAddress>103.233.174.2</tns:ipAddress>"
                    + "                    <tns:sessionId>1</tns:sessionId>"
                    + "                </tns:shopperInformation>"
                    + "            </tns:paymentInformation>"
                    + "        </tns:authorize>"
                    + "    </soapenv:Body>"
                    + "</soapenv:Envelope>";
              
              con.setDoOutput(true);
              DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
              wr.writeBytes(xml);
              wr.flush();
              wr.close();
              String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
              System.out.println(responseStatus);
              BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
              String inputLine;
              StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
              while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                  response.append(inputLine);
              }
              in.close();
              //System.out.println("response:" + response.toString());
              
              Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder()
                .parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(response.toString())));
              NodeList errNodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("ns2:paymentStatus");
              if (errNodes.getLength() > 0) {
                  Element err = (Element)errNodes.item(0);
                  System.out.println("Transaction ID -"+err.getElementsByTagName("ns2:paymentTransactionId").item(0).getTextContent());
                  System.out.println("Order Status -"+err.getElementsByTagName("ns2:orderStatus").item(0).getTextContent());
                  System.out.println("Order Reason -"+err.getElementsByTagName("ns2:orderReason").item(0).getTextContent());
                  System.out.println("Transaction Status -"+err.getElementsByTagName("ns2:paymentTransactionStatus").item(0).getTextContent());
              } else {
                  // success
              }

          } catch (Exception e) {
              System.out.println(e);
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring-Boot is the best and easy way to create ReST APIs. Create a simple spring-boot project. Define a ReST API endpoint accepting user inputs from the front end.

At a high level, you can run your spring-boot app on PORT 6060 and your angular app on PORT 8080. PORT can be anything else for both apps.

CORS changes:

In the spring boot app, you either need to disable CORS or pass angular app-related CORS information to accept any request from the front end.

If you want to avoid CORS then go for a spring-mvc based approach in your spring boot app. Create a form in HTML accepting user inputs and passing that info to a ReST API endpoint either by submitting a form or using ajax call.